# Unable to see the Row and Columns option in the Visualization pane in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have been using Power BI for several weeks, learning BI skills with it

As the image shows, I am now only seeing the "Values" option in the Visualization pane. I cannot see the Row and Columns option any more in the Visualization pane (see the yellow highlighted area of the attached image).

Until a few days ago, I was seeing the "Row" and "Columns" options. But all of a sudden, I can't see them anymore. I see only the "Values" option as the yellow highlighted area shows

Goal: I need to see the Row and Column options to allow me to add the appropriate measures to the Visualization pane (I was seeing them before, but now they appear to have disappeared)

What I have Tried: I have looked unsuccessfully everywhere in Power BI for the feature that will get them to show; I have uninstalled and re-installed Power BI

Image showing row and column features are missing in the Visualization pane
[image: Image showing row and column features are missing in the Visualization pane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you chose the `Table` visual and the `Table` visual just has values. If you choose the `Matrix` visual, you will have rows and columns. The `Matrix` visual is one to the right from the visual you have selected in your screenshot.